# Group homomorphisms and which of the following statements are true (NBHM-$2014$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n\ge2$. Which of the following statements are true?
>
> a. There always exists an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $S_n$.
>
> b. There always exists an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $S_m$ for some $m\lt n$.
>
> c. There always exists an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $GL_n(R)$.

I think b. is right (don't know how to prove though). I also think that c. is false. But not sure.

Comment: **Cayley Theorem**: every finite group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Sym(G)$. And you can find #http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem#. So (a) is right.

Comment: @gaoxinge ..can you say which of these are true ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (a) is right. It is **Cayley Theorem**.
>
> (b) is not right. For example, $|G|=p$ and if $H$ is a subgroup, $|H||(p-1)!$, so if $p$ is a prime, then $|G|\not=|H|$.
>
> (c) is right. Consider the group ring $R(G)$ and you can define it as a linear space. Let $\pi:G\rightarrow{R(G)}$ satisfies $\pi(g):R(G)\rightarrow{R(G)}$:
>
> > $\pi(g)(\sum \sigma_i(g_i))=\sum \sigma_i(gg_i)$

Comment: @gaoxinga I cant under your justification for the option (b). can you explain little bit more clearly please.

Comment: @GA316 Let $|G|=p$ be a prime and $H$ be a subgroup of $S_m,m<p$.  First, because $|S_m|=m!$, then $|H|||S_m||(p-1)!$. Second, if $G=H$, then $|G|=|H|$, that is to say; $p|(p-1)!$.

Comment: @gaoxinga ya. nice. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

(a) is true by Cayley's theorem.

(b) is not true as $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is not a subgroup of $S_2$ and $S_1$.

(c) is true as $S_n$ is isomorphic to the group of all permutation matrices inside $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, so (a) implies (c).