# Does there always exists an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $S_m$ for $m<n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Does there always exists an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $S_m$ for some $m<n$ where $|G|=n$

I know that for $|G|=n$ there is always an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $S_n$

Comment: Have you thought about this at all? What about groups of order $1,2,3,4$,or $5$?

Comment: Same as #http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650841/homomorphisms-and-which-of-the-following-statements-are-truenbhm-2014/650907#650907#.

Comment: Yes, isn't it strange the way the same question with identical wording is asked twice within an hour?

Comment: @DerekHolt actually it appeared in an exam today in India :-)

Answer (score 2):

$C_2$ cannot be embedded in $S_1$.