# Yes/No: There always exists an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $S_n$.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n\ge2$. Is the following statements  true/false?

> There always exists an injective homomorphism from $G$ into $S_n$.

My attempt: I found the answer  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650841/group-homomorphisms-and-which-of-the-following-statements-are-true-nbhm-2014). I think this statement is False.

Take  $G=\mathbb{Z}_{24} $ and $S_8$.

Now $f:\mathbb{Z}_{24} \to S_8$ is not injective.

Here I take $n=8$ and $f$ denotes group homomorphism.

Edit: $f:\mathbb{Z}_{8} \to S_8$ is not injective.

Am I right?

Comment: What is $f$?$\,$

Comment: mapping   from $ G \to  S_8$@Gary

Comment: consider the $G$ action on $G$ by left multiplication, which gives a homomorphism $G\to S_n$.

Comment: The order of your $G$ is not $8$.

Comment: @Gary okay  take $\mathbb{Z_8}$  to $S_8 $.

Comment: But what map is $f$ exactly?

Comment: @Gary i edited  again.  Read  my post

Comment: But there are several homomorphism. Which one is your $f$? Why is it not injective? Where did you prove that it isn't?

Comment: @Gary okay sorry  , you are right    $f:Z_8\to S_8$ is injective

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650891/does-there-always-exists-an-injective-homomorphism-from-g-into-s-m-for-mn) for a counterexample for smaller $n$ than the order of $G$.

Comment: @user12392 It's meaningless to state whether $f: \mathbb{Z}_8 \to S_8$ is injective or not if you don't specify what the morphism actually is. You're only giving the domain and codomain of $f$, but you're not stating what $f(x)$ is given some $x \in \mathbb{Z}_8$. You must at least define the images of some generating set of the domain. For example, if we define $f_1: \mathbb{Z}_8 \to S_8$ such that $f_1(1) = (1\;2\;3\;4\;5\;6\;7\;8)$, then $f_1$ is injective, but if we define$f_2: \mathbb{Z}_8 \to S_8$ such that $f_2(1) = ()$, then $f_2$ is not injective.

Comment: You are asked to consider as setting a group and the symmetric group *of degree equal to the order of the group* ("$n$"). So, why do you consider $\Bbb Z_{24}$, then of order $24$, and $S_8$, then of degree $8$?

Comment: @fitzcarraldo i thought  that we  can take  any  order  .My english  is weak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually Cayley's theorem and it is true **if $n$ is the order of $G$**. The counter-example you suggest has $n = 8 < 24 = |G|$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is true. You have references in the link you posted.

Comment: You have not given a counterexample. Your $f$ has yet to be defined.